# VS won't compile x86

Tags: visual-studio-2012, x86, oledb, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to run an exe which calls Microsoft.ACE.oledb.12.0 but get the error "Provider not registered on local machine".  There has been quite a lot about this error on Stackoverflow.  Recommendations to correct this are to install AccessDatabaeEngine and compiling in x86. I've done both and although the path in project is set to x86 I suspect it is still compiling to 64 bit as VS continues to place the exe in that 64 bit folder.   But I 'm at a lost as to how to correct this.  Any one know how to fix this or confirm if the exe is 32 or 64 bit regardless of which folder it is placed in.  Running vs2012 on windows 2012 server 64bit  (Hyper-v)

regards

Erick

Comment: test indicates the exe to be x86 but still won't accept dll.  Office is 32 bit same as exe.

Comment: Now you know that Visual Studio **is** generating an x86 exe please could you update your post to remove the misleading x64 stuff?  That will keep the question focused on your actual problem.  [ask]

Comment: When you installed AccessDatabaeEngine did you use **AccessDatabaseEngine.exe** or **AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe**?  You may have the x64 provider installed but not the x86 provider?  To run an x86 program successfully you need the x86 provider installed.

Answer (score 0):

ok...so this is what happened. I changed the cpu type to x86 on the project properties.  Which did compile to 32bit but placed it in the incorrect folder. I confirmed this by opening the exe in notepad as there is a way to tell what type it is.

However, the debug version remained at 64 bit.   The fix is to use the drop down list on the toolbar which says "Release" or "Debug" and set it to Configuration manager. In there set both the release and debug values to x86.  This compiles it to x86 and puts it in the correct folder.  I don't know how this is different but it now happily uses the 32 bit dll.